# ErrorProvider using class

Tags: c#, winforms, errorprovider

I have made the following class to avoid the repetition if else code , again and again :

```
public class Error 
{

    private ErrorProvider errProvider;


    public void SetError(Control control, string value)
    {

        errProvider = new ErrorProvider();

        if (control.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            errProvider.SetError(control, value);
        }
        else
        {
            errProvider.SetError(control, "");

        }

    }


}
```

and validation on textbox code is

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

            erp.SetError(textBox1, "Please Enter Name");

    }
```

1. After typing the text in texbox, as I press enter, it working fine;
2. Without Entering any thing in textbox, as I press Enter , it also
   working fine means Waring red icon appears; BUT
3. after warning, as I press tab after entering text in textbox ,
   **warning Icon does not disappear , it sould be removed.**

without class it is working fine with the same code

update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Field Initializer**

```
private readonly ErrorProvider errProvider = new ErrorProvider();
```

You should use Field Initializer for `errProvider`, because every time calling Error.SetError,  ErrorProvider will be constructed, and a constructed ErrorProvider will not only no disappear but also be just layered.

---

[updated]

```
public class Error
{
    private readonly ErrorProvider errProvider = new ErrorProvider();
    public void SetError(Control control, string value)
    {

        if (control.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            errProvider.SetError(control, value);
        }
        else
        {
            errProvider.SetError(control, "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will appreciate, if you provide me full code after changing in my provided code. I am new to c#

Answer (score 0):

Move the construction of your **ErrorProvider** to the declaration line.  So change:

```
private ErrorProvider errProvider;
```

to:

```
private ErrorProvider errProvider = new ErrorProvider();
```

and get rid of the initialization of that member that is currently in your **SetError** method.

It might also prove useful to show us how and when you are creating and storing a reference to the **Error** class instance you are using.

Also, putting your validation code inside of a method that is called **SetError** is a bit misleading (making your code harder to maintain).  I'd name it something like **ValidateControlHasValue** or something like that.